# SQL making last year's data into another column

Tags: sql

I have a data set that looks like:

```
 revenue    country date    
 100    US  3/13/2014
 200    US  3/14/2014
 300    CA  3/13/2014 
 150    US  3/13/2013
 200    CA  3/13/2013
```

How can I run a query to get last year's revenue in the same date into another column?

```
 revenue    country data    revenue_last_year
 100    US  3/13/2014   150
 200    US  3/14/2014   0 or null
 300    CA  3/13/2013   200
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Marc, Can you be a little bit more specific? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For last year's revenue on the given date:

```
select revenue, country, date
  , (
    select revenue
    from revenue r2
    where r1.country=r2.country
      and r1.date = dateadd(yy,1,r2.date)
  ) as LastYearRevenue
from revenue r1
```

Check on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52ccd/9).

Answer (score 1):

Essentialy, you join two queries on the same data set.  Let's say you your table is called CountryRevenue.

SELECT
A.revenue, A.country, A.date, B.revenue as revenue_last_year
FROM
(SELECT * FROM CountryRevenue where YEAR(date) = 2014) AS A
INNER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM Country Revenue WHERE YEAR(date) = 2013) AS B
ON
A.country = B.country

Something like this should do what you want.